# How do you search by lccn using the PHP client?

Tags: google-api-php-client

I am trying to use the Google PHP Client to access information about a book.
I know the LCCN (Library of Congress Control Number) and want to use this as my search key.
I cannot find documentation about how to format this type of key search using the php client (only JSONP).

```
<?php
   require_once 'Google/Client.php';
   require_once 'Google/Service/Books.php';

   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setApplicationName('Get_Book_Covers');
   $client->setDeveloperKey('key goes here');
   $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);

   $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('q=lccn:2005580010');

   foreach ($results as $item) {
      echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to format the search term as lccn:number.

We do the following script:

```
<?php
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Books.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Get_Book_Covers');
$client->setDeveloperKey('my_key');
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$searchTerm = "lccn:91067275";
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes($searchTerm);

foreach ($results as $item) {
  $thumbnail = $item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'];
  echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
  echo "<img src='$thumbnail' alt='hi'/>";
}

?>
```